# Oracle Default null on converion error - timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a trying this:

```
SELECT CAST(COLUMN AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) FROM TABLE;
```

And have error like this:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe not the answer, but you should give the cast an alias.

Comment: Which version of the database are you using? The `DEFAULT ... ON CONVERSION ERROR`-part of the syntax is relatively new and might not be supported yet.

Comment: i have ran the query and it runs in Oracle 18..i am sure that the version of Oracle you are using not supporting WITH TIME ZONE

Comment: What is the data type of column `COLUMN`?

Comment: @Andrew, data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` was introduced long time ago, this cannot be the issue.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes it might be because in the column field my column is date datatype and if it is not then also it might throw an error

Answer (score 3):

Your query runs on Oracle 18c:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column_name VARCHAR2(40) );

INSERT INTO table_name ( column_name )
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSTIMESTAMP ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abcde' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL;

SELECT CAST( column_name AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR ) AS ts FROM table_name;
```

which outputs:

> ```
> | TS                                  |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | 29-OCT-19 10.12.11.106219000 +00:00 |
> | null                                |
> | null                                |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3ef53b154a0e64890b8af6ecbcb62756)*

The `CAST()` function supports the `DEFAULT return_value ON CONVERSION ERROR` syntax from [Oracle 12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75) onwards; that syntax does not appear in the [Oracle 12.1 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions024.htm#SQLRF00613). So you will need to make sure you are using a version where it is supported.

Comment: Thanks, the version was the issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not make much sense.

Either your column data type is `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` then simply use

```
CAST(COLUMN AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
```

Note, the conversion will use the current user session `SESSIONTIMEZONE`, it will never run into a conversion error.

Or your column data type is `VARCHAR2` or `NUMBER`, then provide the format specifier and (if applicable) also the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE.

```
CAST(COLUMN AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
   'YYYY-Mon-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM',
   'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
```